# Magento 2: Debug REST error – 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, rest-api

I can't process orders for some reason. The error I get in the console is:

> POST
>   http://test-site.net/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information
>   400 (Bad Request)

and

> POST
>   https://test-site.net/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/0jue7j2hd7h32jd73hj38wehjsjw8j2j/payment-information
>   400 (Bad Request)

Does anyone know how I would go about debugging this REST error? There's nothing in the `var/log/*.log` files.

Comment: Is your server's date/time correct?
Add a var_dump($e) on the catch of  `submitQuote` method of `vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php`

Comment: main.CRITICAL: Invalid customer address id 57 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): Invalid customer address id 57 at /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteAddressValidator.php:79)"}

Comment: For above, 400 issue I am getting this in exception log.